# Spacing after background image

Tags: html, css

Where does this space after my background image come frome? (red line in image shows spacing)
The background image does not have this space, it end where the black color ends...

```
#menu{
    width:300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:url(../img/menuBackground.png) right no-repeat;  
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
```

[image]

It should go nicely and completly to the right side of the div...

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Where is the right edge of `#menu`? Is the space due to the element for the copyright date?  Try adding a border around the `#menu` element to make sure that the edges are where you expect them to be.

Comment: Mind creating a JSFiddle?

Comment: @pablito.aven, thank you for directing me to jsfiddle.
while putting the code, i noticed there was no problem with my code, but me who was confused by me own image...
See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was me who was confused:
This solved it:

```
background:url(../img/menuBackground.jpg) right top no-repeat;
```

Because only the middle of the image was shown, it looked as if there was spacing:[image]

Answer (score 2):

try changing top: right: and height: to see what you come up with also add position fixed unless you have this somewhere else, i don't know where the rest of your code is.

```
  #menu
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;    /*maybe try positioning it fixed where you want it*/
    right:0px;    /*same here or left:0;*/
    width:300px;
    height:250px;  /*you could also try using height*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:url(../img/menuBackground.png) right no-repeat;  
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
   }
```

Comment: you made me think.
The problem was wit the position of the background image:
This solved my problem:
background:url(../img/menuBackground.jpg) right top no-repeat;
Given that my image is higher then the menu and i didnt see it was vertically aligned to the middle.
Becaus of the diagonal end,it seemd there was a spacing

Comment: i had the same issue kinda simular and used this to fix it before haha, didn't even notice

background:url(../img) no-repeat center 0,#000 url() left top;